# How to fetch a message in a channel gotten via guild.channels.get

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on improvements for my reaction based cart tracker for discord shops (ie in game items etc)

I'm having an issue where after getting a channel by id, i can't use the fetchMessage function on the variable i saved the channel to to get a specific message. i need this to automatically update the cart message ive already sent upon the user reacting to add an item.

heres my current code:

```
var cartchannel = messageReaction.message.guild.channels.get(curcart.orderchannelid)
var cartmsg = cartchannel.fetchMessage(curcart.cartmsgid)
```

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that your channel is found?

Comment: yes, it finds the channel fine. when i go to grab the message it tells me fetchMessage isnt a function.
it grabs the channel as a guildChannel, which doesnt have the fetchMessage function, instead of a textChannel, which does

Comment: Weird. Can you add `console.log(Discord.version);` and send the result here please?

Comment: its on v 11.5.1

Comment: Ive tried another suggestion to check the channel to see if it returns its type as text, and it does, but the fetchmessage option is still unavailable, and when i try it anyways, it returns Promise { <pending> } when i log it to console.

Comment: Oh I see. Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channel.fetchMessage()` is an **asynchronous** function. It means you need to use `await` or `.then()`. For example with **await**:

```js
var cartchannel = messageReaction.message.guild.channels.get(curcart.orderchannelid)
var cartmsg = await cartchannel.fetchMessage(curcart.cartmsgid) 
console.log(cartmsg) // Discord.Message object
```

or with **.then()**:

```js
var cartchannel = messageReaction.message.guild.channels.get(curcart.orderchannelid)
cartchannel.fetchMessage(curcart.cartmsgid).then((cartmsg) => {
    console.log(cartmsg) // Discord.Message object
});
```

If you use the `await` way, you need to be in an async function.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.